# What are the hookshot ledges for?

Tags: hyrule-warriors

I noticed areas on Legend Mode maps that are only accessible by Hookshot, much earlier than when you actually obtain the Hookshot. For example, there's one in the north of Hyrule Field, the first area of the game (and, if you're just following the story checkpoints, it's quite far out of your way). There's also ones in Eldin Caves and Faron Woods.

Naturally, I assumed there'd be *secret goodies* for players who came back later after getting the Hookshot and climbed up there (a chest, perhaps) - but after returning later myself to do just that, I  found the area above completely empty.

Is there ever anything up there? Does an event need to be triggered for something to occur? Or is it aways just empty?

Comment: Gold Skulltulas can appear there, IIRC.  However, the skulltulas have conditions like X enemies killed or playing as Y character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases these are skulltulas (in the Goron level, a skulltula appears here, for example. They may appear because of an objective or because of the base "kill 1000 enemies," but in general they house skulltulas.